# Button background-image toggle not going back to original background-image

Tags: javascript, button, toggle

```
function myFunction() {
var element = document.body;
element.classList.toggle("light-mode");
var btndrk = document.getElementById('drk');
if (btndrk.style.backgroundImage === "url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg')") {
onlick(btndrk.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/sun.svg')");
} else {
btndrk.style.backgroundImage = "url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg')";
}
```

}

```
#drk {
position: relative;
height: 70%;
width: 3.3%;
top: 15%;
background-color: rgb(105, 50, 255);
color: white;
font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
border-radius: 5px;
background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg');
background-size: 45% 45%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
border-radius: 50%;
border: none;
transition: all 200ms linear;
box-shadow: 0 0 1vw rgba(255,235,167,.25);
```

}

```
<button id="drk" onclick="myFunction()"></button>
```

I want to have the original background image come back on the second click and the sun.SVG show on the third and so-on and so-fourth. Right now the original background-image shows when I refresh the page but after one click it changes to sun.SVG and does not change back. I want it to toggle between the two.

Comment: Please edit your question and place code in `code` blocks properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do the image change in JS.

The JS can simply be:

```
document.getElementById('drk').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
});
```

And for the CSS part you need to add:

```
body.light-mode #drk {
    background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg');
}
body:not(.light-mode) #drk {
    background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/sun.svg');
}
```

```js
document.getElementById('drk').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
});
```

```css
html,body{height:100px;}

#drk {
    position: relative;
    height: 70%;
    width: 3.3%;
    top: 15%;
    background-color: rgb(105, 50, 255);
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Advent Pro', sans-serif;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/sun.svg');
    background-size: 45% 45%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: none;
    transition: all 200ms linear;
    box-shadow: 0 0 1vw rgba(255,235,167,.25);
}
body:not(.light-mode) {
    background: #555;
}
body.light-mode #drk {
    background-image: url('https://assets.codepen.io/1462889/moon.svg');
}
```

```html
<button id="drk"></button>
```

Comment: This worked! The only thing i did different was to put the javascript as this function myFunction() {
    document.body.classList.toggle("light-mode");
}

Comment: Yes I've noticed that I just changed it so you can see it is easier this way. Obviously I just wrote that as a reference.
You can mark this as the working answer if you want :)